# Validate that DataTable cell is not null or empty

Tags: c#, datatable, null

I would like to check if the value in a Data Table cell is either null or empty/blank space. The `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` method does not work as the `row["ColumnName"]` is considered an `object`.

Do I need to do a compound check like the following or is there something more elegant?

```
if (row["ColumnName"] != DBNull.Value && row["ColumnName"].ToString().Length > 0)
{
  // Do something that requires the value to be something other than blank or null
}
```

I also thought of the following ...

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["Amt Claimed"].ToString()))
{
  // Do something that requires the value to be something other than blank or null
}
```

but I figured if the value of the cell was `null` an exception would be thrown when trying to convert to a string using `ToString()`

Comment: Check if the data row is not null with `DataRow.IsNull(string columnName)`: `if (!row.IsNull("ColumnName")){//Check for empty string here}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A null value would be returned as `DBNull`, and not a null literal.

```
var tab = new System.Data.DataTable();
tab.Columns.Add("c1");
tab.Rows.Add();

tab.Rows[0]["c1"] = null;
tab.Rows[0]["c1"].GetType() //returns DBNull
```

And as the DBNull.ToString() is [guaranteed to return an empty string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull.tostring?view=netframework-4.8), you can safely use `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))`.

You can always guard against not being sure if an object is null by simply using null coalescing.

```
!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value?.ToString()))
```